# AS3. Class flash.system::Worker could not be found

Tags: actionscript-3, worker, verifyerror

I can't solve the problem with the Worker class in ActionScript project. I get:

> VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.system::Worker could not be found

As i searched, VerifyError means that the SWC file is corrupted. How should i fix it ?

Code is simple (Variable of worker Declared) and no additional code except this worker exists.

Tried updating playerglobal SWC with the newest 16 version. Tried updating my Adobe flash professional 5.5, Flash player.

In my projects settings the latest player i can choose to work with is "Flash player 10.2". How could i update it ? or is it the latest ?

```
import flash.System.Worker;
public class workerService extends Sprite {
   var worker:Worker;
      public function workerService() {
      }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is almost no code. Edited post.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  BTW, swf-version goes up to 28; version 16 is actually quite outdated.

Comment: No. As i remember i did the task in the other way without using worker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the worker class got implemented in Flash Player version 11.4. I'm not sure how to update the SDK in Flash 5.5 though, but maybe this link helps:
https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/overlay-air-sdk-flash-professional1.html

Or just use an ide like flashdevelop.

Answer (score 0):

Add compile flag "swf-version=17" to your flash project and install the latest FlashPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

Add Additional compiler arguments in properties as show in below image

[image: A]